# delete old files series except the last one file

Tags: php, linux, filter

The files are listed by category.
Processed in file name in `YYYYMMDDHHMM` format.
how do I delete the **oldest** files except the latest one by this file name?

```
"10MX232 .201801070702.txt" >>old file
"10MX232 .201801080703.txt" >>old file
"10MX232 .201801161651.txt" >>old file
"10MX232 .201801181531.txt" >>old file
"10MX232 .201805120846.txt" >>----new file


"1465LY1 .201804051311.txt" >>old file
"1465LY1 .201805101441.txt" >>old file
"1465LY1 .201805110912.txt" >>old file
"1465LY1 .201805111419.txt" >>----new file

"17NX232 .201801250054.txt" >>old file
"17NX232 .201801260055.txt" >>old file
"17NX232 .201801270055.txt" >>old file
"17NX232 .201801280056.txt" >>old file
"17NX232 .201801290057.txt" >>old file
"17NX232 .201801300058.txt" >>----new file
```

i want this result

```
ls
10MX232 .201805120846.txt
1465LY1 .201805111419.txt
17NX232 .201801300058.txt
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
run_path=./testlog/
declare -a file_nm
declare -a file_id
declare -i x
declare -i id_count
x=0

ls -1 $run_path | while read -r idpc; do
 x+=1
 idpc2=$(echo $idpc | cut -c1-7)
 file_id[$x]=$idpc2
 file_nm[$x]=$idpc
 id_count=$(ls -l $run_path${file_id[x]}* | grep -v ^l | wc -l)
 if [ "$id_count" -ge 2 ];then
  rm $(echo "$run_path${file_nm[x]}")
 fi
done
```